# Why do I have to add execjs and therubyracer to my gemfile for rails3.1 to work?

Tags: rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.1, execjs

I don't like being in situations where I don't understand why something is working. I feel like I am using a trash bag and a rubber-band to fix a leaky pipe. Since upgrading to rails3.1 I have not been able to get it to work unless I add 'execjs' and 'therubyracer' to the gemfile. I do not understand what these gems even do. I just read somewhere on stackoverflow that you had to add them for the app to work. Anyone know what these gems are for?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

ExecJs - gives you the ability to, well - execute Javascript

RubyRacer - gives you the interface from Ruby to V8 engine.

Both are dependencies of the `coffee-script` gem, which is used by Rails 3.1 and the asset pipeline.

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot. Very straight forward and simple answer. Now I am wondering why they didn't just include these in the default gems for rails 3.1 since they are dependencies of coffee-script.

Comment: Is there any way to add these gems into the default gems for rails 3.1? Is there a template Gemfile on disk somewhere?

Comment: Is there any way to get rid of the coffee-script dependency in rails?

Comment: therubyracer is not a dependency of `coffee-script`

Comment: @KeatingWang is correct. Only execjs is a dependency of coffee-script.

Comment: if it's a dependency, then why should it be in the gemfile? wouldn't bundler put it in gemfile.lock automatically?

Answer (score 5):

ExecJS supports these runtimes:

therubyracer - Google V8 embedded within Ruby

therubyrhino - Mozilla Rhino embedded within JRuby

Node.js

Apple JavaScriptCore - Included with Mac OS X

Microsoft Windows Script Host (JScript)

---

therubyracer is not necessary, you can use any of the js runtimes instead, for example I use Node.js.